# AWS ALB returning 502 from Lambda instead of custom HTTP status

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

I've created a Lambda that check on a DynamoDB table the existence of a record matching host and request path and, if found, returns a redirect to the matching URL.

My Lambda returns this response but the ALB returns 502.

```
{
    "statusCode": 301,
    "statusDescription": null,
    "headers": {
        "Location": "https://www.my-target.co.uk/"
    },
    "multiValueHeaders": null,
    "body": "Redirecting to https://www.my-target.co.uk/",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

This is the log I find in CloudWatch for the Lambda function

```
START RequestId: 8b5a28f2-c56d-4418-a7b9-66ebe0ba2470 Version: $LATEST
[Information] EMG.ApplicationLoadBalancerRequestHandler: Received: GET / 
[Information] EMG.ApplicationLoadBalancerRequestHandler: Processing: my-test.net / 
[Information] EMG.RedirectManagers.RedirectTableRedirectManager: Fetching item: my-test.net / from table redirect-table 
[Information] EMG.ApplicationLoadBalancerRequestHandler: Found: https://www.target.co.uk/ Permanent 
END RequestId: 8b5a28f2-c56d-4418-a7b9-66ebe0ba2470
REPORT RequestId: 8b5a28f2-c56d-4418-a7b9-66ebe0ba2470  Duration: 69.59 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 39 MB
```

This is the response I get

```
HTTP/1.1 502
status: 502
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Thu, 15 Aug 2019 19:13:58 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 138
Connection: keep-alive
<html>
 <head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
 <body bgcolor="white">
 <center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I couldn't find anything saying we can't return non-200 responses from Lambda, so I really have no idea...

You can also find this question in the relevant GitHub repo: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/507

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently I was missing a required property of the returned HTTP response.

Here is the relevant part of the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/lambda-functions.html#respond-to-load-balancer) (emphasis mine)

> The response from your Lambda function must include the Base64 encoding status, status code, status description, and headers. You can omit the body. **The statusDescription header must contain the status code and reason phrase, separated by a single space**.

Changing my code so that the response of the Lambda complied to the requirement fixed the issue.

```
{
    "statusCode": 301,
    "statusDescription": "301 Found",
    "headers": {
        "Location": "https://www.my-target.co.uk/"
    },
    "multiValueHeaders": null,
    "body": "Redirecting to https://www.my-target.co.uk/",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

Comment: For future folks, the linked AWS documentation has now changed to remove the instructions around *statusDescription*, so I don't think this answer is still relevant.